# How to send keys to a minimized window in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have just started learning C++. At the moment I am stack at a small thing which I cannot find a solution to yet. I hope someone can help me out on this matter.

My goal: I want to send a couple of keystrokes to an running application. But when the application has no focus i.e. is minimized or what so ever, the keystrokes should still be
send to the application.

My problem: When I use the function `sendkey()` with `VK_KEY` or what ever (don't remember lol) then it is working BUT only if the window is maximized (focused), but when I try using `PostMessage(GameWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, 'G', 0);` nothing happens.

I tried it on Notepad, but also on the application which I want it to work but nothing.

I think I need to hook to the process and then send the keys, unfortunately I have no problem with C++ (unless you go totally pro lol) but I have no experience what so ever with hooking and that kind of stuff.

Can anyone send me in the right direction or write me a small tutorial on how to do such a thing, for example with one of the Windows games?

```
if( amount != 0 )
{
    // bring the window to the front
    HWND GameWindow = FindWindow(0, L"Naamloos - Kladblok");
    SetForegroundWindow(GameWindow);

    // execute the loop
    for( int i = 0; i < amount; i++ ){
    // not the last loop so add a pause at the end
    if( i < (amount-1))
    {
        PostMessage(GameWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, 'G', 0);
        PostMessage(GameWindow, WM_KEYUP, 'G', 0);
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    // last loop so dont add a pause at the end
    else
    {
        PostMessage(GameWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, 'G', 0);
        PostMessage(GameWindow, WM_KEYUP, 'G', 0);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't check for errors. Are you sure that `FindWindow` is succeeding? `SetForegroundWindow` like that won't work. Read the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes it is working, i see the notepad window popping up, and when I use sendkeys instead of anything else like PostMessage, it does work correctly ;) So the code is correct, it is just that PostMessage wont do a thing ;  ;

Comment: Well, sometimes you can fake input like this, and sometimes it just doesn't work. You could try targeting the EDIT window within Notepad. But as for your game who knows. Perhaps we could help better if you explained why you were trying to fake input to your game.

Comment: David Heffernan, nothing special in particular, just a learning process for me. In game you can talk to people, to repeat a text you can simply open the chat box by pressing the "space key". To repeat the last message yuo have send you just press the "up key" and then press "enter key" to show the message. This is what I would like to automate. Since I just started learning GUI programming (been doing console applications so far) I tought this would be a nice start but I cant get the PostMessage thing to work like stated in my first post ;)

Comment: It's a non-trivial problem. And it's going to be awfully hard to give a generic answer. At best you would need to specify the target application. I'm afraid "Naamloos - Kladblok" means nothing to me! If I were you I'd look for something easier to help your learning process.

Comment: "Naamloos - Kladblok" means "Untitled - Notepad" haha, I am dutch thats why the strange name ;)

Comment: OK, but the thing is once you find a way to make it work for Notepad, you'll likely find that you need different tricks for the true target. What's more some games use DirectX for input and I think that's a little different in the way input is handled.

Comment: For what it's worth, trying to send input to a non-focused app is generally not supported; not something I'd recommend as a starter project, because you'll be working *against* Windows right from the start. Windows has a bunch of internal infrastructure for processing input and routing it appropriately, and if you try to bypass that, the target app may or may not behave as expected, depending on what input-related functions the app uses. It's definitely easier to start by writing an app that receives input from Windows than one that tries to make another app think that Windows sent it input.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The way a Win32 application behaves to Windows messages is completely at its own discretion. So it could be that your target window/app is receiving the messages and just choosing to ignore them. You can use Microsoft Spy++ (comes with Visual Studio) to watch the target apps message queue and see what it receives.

For what its worth, Notepad (v5.1) chooses to listen to WM_CHAR messages (instead of WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP), even when minimized (sample code below).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND hwndWindowTarget;
    HWND hwndWindowNotepad = FindWindow(NULL, L"Untitled - Notepad");
    if (hwndWindowNotepad)
    {
        // Find the target Edit window within Notepad.
        hwndWindowTarget = FindWindowEx(hwndWindowNotepad, NULL, L"Edit", NULL);
        if (hwndWindowTarget)
        {
            PostMessage(hwndWindowTarget, WM_CHAR, 'G', 0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the process has no sub windows such as `"Edit"`?